# 14.04.04 amd 64 installation issues

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 64-bit

Installed from usb....14.04.04-amd-64. Fresh install, did not retain windows. At "Installation Type", I selected only the Erase and Install option. Everything installed ok the best I could tell. However, im getting what i think are video issues. Some windows open completely scrambled and illegible. I have NVIDEA GeForce 7150 M / nForce 630M showing as Display Adaptor Type. I tried search and additional drivers, selected the first option. Seems to be worse. Does this sound like driver related problem? Also, not sure it matters but the laptop has 4gb ram installed, shows 3.6gb as usable. Should I have installed 32 bit even though im 64 bit capable?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an nvVidia graphics driver issue. You can find out your compatible driver like this
[image]

You can install it by:

1. uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers.
2. Boot the computer
3. When the GRUB menu appears, highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
4. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the line.
5. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot the Ubuntu operating system.
6. When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
7. Enter your user name and the password
8. Execute :

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
   sudo reboot
   ```
9. install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers.
   10 Boot the computer,
10. when the GRUB menu appears, highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
11. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the line.
12. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot the Ubuntu operating system.
13. When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
14. Enter your user name and the password
15. Execute :

    ```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
    sudo reboot
    ```

**Note:** I have the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M and this driver is working fine for me.

You can find out whether you have 64 bit processor or not [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/36547/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q8200-(4M-Cache-2_33-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB))

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/738250/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)**

Comment: sure also would like to know how you make this button kind of enclosure around the Ctrl or Alt or F1?

Comment: Well, if you [edit] your answer it'll become obvious. You'll see I use it too to simulate buttons like OK and Cancel...  **;-)**